# Android OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect Provider

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I created my own OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect Provider using IdentityServer4 in ASP.NET Core. I am now trying to create an Android app (my very first Android app) that uses my provider to authenticate the users, using the Authentication Code + PKCE flow.

I looked around for a client SDK for Android, and found one called AppAuth, https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android. But it looks like it is not to a full release, since that last release was 0.7.1, which was released a year and a half ago. Should this be used? Should I worry about it not being >= 1.x.x? Any good tutorials on implementing the Authentication Code + PKCE flow?

I also heard that maybe AccountManager might be what I am looking for. I could not find any documentation on how to implement OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect flows via AccountManager. Anyone know have a good tutorial how to do this?

Any other suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Interested in thoughts on alternative standards based libraries also.

As far as I'm aware this remains the most respected library that works across vendors - but they have been struggling for contributors.

The likes of Okta and Auth0 have good Android libraries worth borrowing ideas from. They may be vendor specific in places though.

Out of interest I integrated AppAuth into a fairly complete (Kotlin / Single Activity) sample recently, so it seems to work fine with the latest Android tech:

- [Write up + code sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)

I found the reliability and usability tricky, since Chrome Custom Tabs adds some technical complexity.